# Django Faker Recursive Foreign Key

Tags: django, faker, factory-boy

I am trying to create a seeding script using Faker. In my models.ContentCategory, the `parent_category` has a recursive foreign key. However, I could not find a way to translate this into my faker script. I am really open to all kinds of helps!

here is my models.py:

```py
class ContentCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, parent_link=True,
    )
    # down here should be fixed after creating the sections model
    parent_section = models.ForeignKey(
        Sections, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "content category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Content Categories"
```

and here is the handler snippet:

```py
#seeding Content Category
        for _ in range(4):
            name = fake.word(ext_word_list=None)
            description = fake.sentence(nb_words=15, variable_nb_words=True, ext_word_list=None)
            #creating ids and parent ids
            cid = random.randint(1,4)
            # creating key for Sections
            ptid = random.randint(1,14)
            ContentCategory.objects.create(
                name=name, description=description, parent_category=cid, parent_section=ptid
            )
            check_content_categories = ContentCategory.objects.count().all()
```

here is the full error log:

```
 python manage.py seed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/myyagis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/myyagis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/myyagis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/myyagis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/myyagis/meethaq/be/be/api/management/commands/seed.py", line 104, in handle
    ContentCategory.objects.create(
  File "/home/myyagis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myyagis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 420, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/home/myyagis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 483, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/home/myyagis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 206, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "ContentCategory.parent_category" must be a "ContentCategory" instance.
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

In the model, the foreign key tables were already accepting `blank=True, null=True`, hence, I discarded these from the seeder script, it automatically filled the db with the null values.

Better solutions for non-nullable fields :

`Model.objects.order_by('?').first()` confirmed using.

recursive foreign key accepts the model's own name as the Model name.

example for the model UserCategory:

```py
for _ in range(200):
            category = UserCategory.objects.order_by('?').first()
            email = fake.unique.ascii_free_email()
            password = fake.unique.word(ext_word_list=None)
            gender =fake.api_gender()
            first_name = fake.unique.first_name()
            last_name = fake.unique.last_name()
            phone_number = fake.country_calling_code() + fake.phone_number()
            birthday = fake.unique.date_of_birth()
```